# Tag synonim/Prune request [vs2012]->[visual-studio-2012]

Tags: support

Seems that whe have two tags

**vs2012**   and  **visual-studio-2012**

Can anyone prune one of the dupe or at last make it a synonim? Seems they where both created by the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was only 1 question using the vs2012 tag so I just removed it... lets use [visual-studio-2012](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012).

Comment: That was what I thinked, too. Thanks, Kit.